# Where can i get touch sensitive buttons with RGB-LED like in Ableton Push

Tags: button

I am searching for this component: a touch sensitive button with LEDs like in the [Ableton Push](http://46.20.46.151/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/push_01_72dpi_rgb-632x412.jpg) or in other Launchpads. Does anyone have an idea about where I can buy something like this? The best would be an RGB LED.

This is what I've [found](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10442) so far. It has no RGB LED though.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1929 ?

Comment: Touch-sensitive? As in, an on/off switch? I've seen kits (such as the ones mentioned in comments and answers), but none that are pressure-sensitive

Answer (score 3):

Just a little more searching would have led you to [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7835), along with its associated [breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8033), bezels, and LEDs.

Answer (score 3):

The specific buttons you link to are custom made. They're not something you can buy off the shelf. In fact they aren't even buttons.

What they are is a translucent moulded silicone rubber sheet with conductive pads behind (typically in a ring shape) with an LED mounted on a PCB behind them.  The pad is pressed, which flexes the silicone rubber, to press the conductive portion against exposed tracks on the PCB behind.

There are some similar products around, such as [the Sparkfun one Ignacio points to](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7835) but it is highly unlikely you will find anything off-the-shelf that does exactly what you want.  Coupling a pre-moulded translucent rubber keypad membrane (if you can find one somewhere) with your own custom designed PCB to take the RGB LEDs you want (preferably surface mount to keep the size small enough) and provide the exposed tracks is probably the only way you can get exactly what you want.

You may be able to create your own sheet by first making a suitable mould, maybe with wood or modelling clay or something like that, then filling it with silicone (translucent bathroom sealant) and then impress on the back of that a second mould to provide the contact points and indents etc. Then, after a few days when it's all dry, add to the contact points some self-adhesive copper foil, or paint them with conductive paint. Don't quote me on that though, I haven't tried it ;)